# Can't Cascade Deletes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class called `Point` which can be included in a number of other classes, so the structure looks something like this:

```
public class foo
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual Point ImageCenter { get; set; }
}
public class bar
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual Point ImageCenter { get; set; }
}
public class Point
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

`Point` has a 1 to 1 relationship with either `foo` or `bar`.

What I'm trying to do is when I delete a `foo` or a `bar` that the referenced `Point` will also get deleted.

If I set `Point` to `[Required]` the deletion cascades in reverse (i.e. if I delete a `Point` the `foo` or `bar` gets deleted).<--This is the opposite of what I want

Comment: I would imagine you would want points as attributes, not another table.

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated than what I've described.  Point does a bit more than just store two `int`s.

Comment: When Point is a little more elaborate it might be a candidate for a base class. That way a Bar : Point would have 1 Id. Withseparate IDs this is neither a proper Relational or OOP design.

Comment: That's a good idea...I'd have to think on that for a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want with just Entity framework (actually the limitation is the foreign keys themselves not EF).

To get what you want you would need to create a trigger on `DELETE` and `UPDATE` on `foo` and `bar` to check to see if `Point` is unused and if it is then deleted it. (If you are deleting a `foo` you will not need to only check if any `bar`s use it but also if any other `foo`s use it too)

Comment: Is there a way to create triggers in EF?

Comment: Depends on the version and if you want the triggers automatically generated in your upgrade scripts or if you are willing to hand write them in in to your `Up()` and `Down()` function of your migrations. There is no native support, but later versions of EF allow you to write your own plugins to add features like that. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519921.aspx) for a basic example where the writer adds support for automatically creating Data Table Views (in the section "Create Custom Migration Operations").

Comment: EF 6.1.  Maybe I'll investigate the plugins.

Comment: Unless you plan on doing it a lot I would recommend just hand editing your `Up()` and `Down()` migration functions to do create and remove the trigger via a [`Sql(string, bool, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql(v=vs.113).aspx) call

Comment: After a quick search I tend to agree.  Ugh.  I really don't like burying code inside the migrations...is there somewhere else to do this?  Maybe in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: What I do is I put the SQL query in a file like `AddTriggerA.sql` and `DropTriggerA.sql` then add them as embedded resources to my project. Then in my migration I do `Sql(SqlScripts.AddTriggerA);` (I also add a custom resource file called `SqlScripts.resx` instead of using the default one with the project)